# Rigid body simulation always has a visible collision space

Tags: physics, rigid-body-simulation

Every time I use the rigid body tools I have a visible space between the passive object and the active object, even when I set the collision margin to very small or zero.  Any suggestions?

Comment: What are you using the rigid body tools for when this happens?

Comment: Can you upload your .blend or some screenshots? As it is now, we don't have enough information to do much more that speculate.

Comment: The blend is here: http://www.pasteall.org/blend/24900 I usual use the Rigid body tools to drop items onto a surface or other basic use.  It doesn't seem to matter how simple the scene is I still have this problem.

Comment: Ah, I thought you meant the rigid body tools panel in the *3D view `T` > Tool shelf*. In the file you linked the backdrop still has a collision margin of `4cm` and the monkey `0.1cm`.

Comment: that's my mistake I was only adjusting the collision margin of the dropped object not the surface, thanks:)  I had no idea subsurf was affecting it though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be caused by the Subsurf modifier on the Suzanne.

Frame `124` with the Subsurf modifier:

[image]

Frame `124` with the Subsurf applied:

[image]

In addition the Backdrop had a collision margin of `4cm`, in the images above it is set to `0`.

Comparison of frame `124` with the collision margin of the BackDrop set to `4cm` and `0m`:

[image] [image]

I also set the *Collision shape* of the Suzanne to *Convex Hull* and disabled *Collision margin*.

Comment: The reason for this is that currently rigid bodies only use the base mesh of the object. Things like modifiers and shape keys are not taken into account.
In future versions it will be possible to select the mesh source.